# Autoscalable background image

Tags: c#, vb.net, xna

I have got .png HD (1024x768) backgroud image. My users could have different screen sizes, but it should look always the same, so:

Is that possible to automatically scale it size to the background size in [xna](/questions/tagged/xna)?

Comment: Yes, it should definitely be possible.

Comment: What research have you done?  Any code to show?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to render whole scene into `RenderTarget` and then draw it using rectangle for position and size.

```
Rectangle dest = new Rectangle (0, 0, graphics.ViewPort.Width, graphics.ViewPort.Height);
spriteBatch.Draw(RenderTarget, dest, Color.White);
```

it could looks stretched/squeezed if you work in 16:9 and user have 4:3 then:

```
int height = (int)(graphics.ViewPort.Width * (16.0/9.0));
Rectangle dest = new Rectangle (0, graphics.ViewPort.Height -- (int)(height / 2.0), graphics.ViewPort.Width, graphics.ViewPort.Height);
spriteBatch.Draw(RenderTarget, dest, Color.White);
```

or in general where width >= height:

```
double aspectratio = ((double)graphics.ViewPort.Width / (double)graphics.Viewport.Height);
int height = (int)(graphics.ViewPort.Width * aspectratio;
Rectangle dest = new Rectangle(0, graphics.ViewPort.Height - (int)(height / 2.0), graphics.ViewPort.Width, height);
```

and here is some nice example of independed screen resolution:

http://www.david-amador.com/2010/03/xna-2d-independent-resolution-rendering/